# How to declare and initialize an array with key/values using JavaScript and then dynamically creating select dropdown

Tags: javascript

How to declare and initialize an array with key/values using JavaScript and then dynamically creating select dropdown and assigning key/values to the options using JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be easier if you use JQuery... This is how it would be done in basic Javascript.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span id="selectContainer"></span>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var selectItems = {
            me: "Hari Gangadharan",
            friend1: "Asif Aktar",
            friend2: "Jay Thomas",
            friend3: "John Abrams"
        }

        selectItems["newFriend"] = "Niel Goldman";

        var selectContainer = document.getElementById("selectContainer");
        var selectBox = document.createElement("SELECT");
    selectBox.id = selectBox.name = "friendList";
        selectContainer.appendChild(selectBox);
        for (var key in selectItems) {
            var value = selectItems[key];
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
            option.text = value;
            option.value = key;
            selectBox.options.add(option);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You're not looking for an array for this, you should use an object, for instance :

```
var list = {"some option": 1, "another option": 2, "etc": 3};
```

To therefore insert these to a dropdown you could append it to an existing option list by doing

```
for(var optionText in options) {
    var option = new Option(optionText, options[listText], true, false)
    document.getElementById("listName").options.add(option)
}
```

Combined the code may look something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {"some option": 1, "another option": 2, "etc": 3};
window.onload = function() {
    for(var optionText in options) {
        var option = new Option(optionText, options[listText], true, false)
        document.getElementById("listName").options.add(option)
    }
}
</script>
<select id="listName">
</select>
```

I hope that helps, it should be more than enough for you to get started.

---

Edit : You should obviously note that doing window.onload and replacing it with a function like that may cause undesired effects if you have existing code, so either make use of your existing library's loaded functions etc

Comment: Thank you for ur help. But I want "some option" to be the text and 1 to be the value.